# iPhone How can I play more then one live Streams without delay

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have list of live streams, and showing these streams in horizontally, When i swipe other Stream would come respectively for all Streams. **My problem is when I swipe to second stream i don't want delay, Second stream should already playing**,

I Can also purchase any third-party for this problem, Or another solution would be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MPMovieplayerController,you can't play multiple video at a time.
You can use **AVFoundation.framework** for this purpose.MediaPlayer.framework uses low level AVFoundation framework to play videos.It is clearly explained in [this blog](http://iosguy.com/2012/01/11/multiple-video-playback-on-ios/)